# Logical operators to only be false when both of them are non-null or non-empty string

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I want the logical operator to be true only if the following conditions are met:

1. Either A or B has `null` or have an empty string, meaning at least one of them will have something i.e. `!((A === null) || (A === '')) || !((B === null) || (B === ''))`
2. A and B are both null or have empty string

Basically, the only time I want the condition to be false is when A and B have both non-null or non-empty string at the same time.

Comment: what means "*either*" in this context? do you have a table of truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the values and chain the conditions with logical OR.

```js
const check = (a, b) => a === null || a === '' || b === null || b === '';

//        the above is the same as this, like the text requests
//        (a === null || a === '') !== (b === null || b === '') ||
//        (a === null || a === '') && (b === null || b === '');
    

console.log([
    [null, null], //  true
    [null, ''],   //  true
    ['', null],   //  true
    ['', ''],     //  true
    [1, 1],       // false
    [null, 1],    //  true
    [1, null]     //  true
].map(a => check(...a)));
```

Comment: can I ask why the arguments are in an array?

Comment: just for having only `check` as mapping callback.

Answer (score 1):

The below condition will work if A and B are null, undefined, 0 and ''(empty).

if(!A || !B || A==='' || B===''){}

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this ?

```js
let test = (a,b) => {
  return !(a != null && b != null) || !( a != '' && b != '')
}

console.log(test(null, null))
console.log(test('', ''))
console.log(test('a','b'))
console.log(test(null,'b'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Can be simplified while assigning one of the null or ""**

```js
let test = (a = "", b = "") => {
  if(a === null) a = ""
  if(b === null) b = ""
  return !( a != '' && b != '')
}

console.log(test(null, null))
console.log(test('', ''))
console.log(test('a','b'))
console.log(test(null,'b'))
```